# How to remove an element from a multiway tree in Prolog

Tags: tree, prolog

My friends and I are quite struggling with this task. In any other language this would be easy.

We tried converting the tree into a list, remove an element and then building a tree. The build from list to tree building part we have no clue how to do.

How would I go about it with this tree:

```ml
tree(1, [tree(6, [tree(7, [])] ),
         tree(3, []),
         tree(2, [tree(4, []), 
                  tree(5, [])])
        ])
```

Would be immensely grateful for any nudges or solutions.

Comment: What did you try? What is not working with that?

Comment: We tried converting the tree into a list, remove an element and then building a tree. The build from list to tree building part we have no clue how to do

Comment: But you do not need to convert it first to a list. You can recursively make new nodes, a bit similar to a *finger tree*.

Comment: create new nodes? So from the node which I delete I need to create new nodes from the node I deleted? How would I go about with this tree: tree(1, [tree(6,[tree(7,[])]),tree(3,[]),tree(2,[tree(4,[]),tree(5,[])])])

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, with the example you gave in the comment, I understand better. I give you an example for removing the node with given value Elm. This is a double recursion, one for handling the functor tree and another for handling lists.

```
remove_elem_from_tree(Elm, tree(V, Nodes), tree(V,Nodes1) ):-
    Elm \= V,
    remove_elem_from_list(Elm, Nodes, Nodes1).
    
    remove_elem_from_list(_, [], []).
    remove_elem_from_list(E, [X|Xs], [Y|Ys]) :-
        remove_elem_from_tree(E, X, Y), !, 
        remove_elem_from_list(E, Xs, Ys).
    remove_elem_from_list(E, [_|Xs], Ys) :-
        remove_elem_from_list(E, Xs, Ys).
```

So example run is: remove the node 4

```
?- remove_elem_from_tree(4, tree(1, 
        [   tree(6, [tree(7, [])]),
            tree(3, []),
            tree(2, [tree(4, []),tree(5, [])])
        ]
      ), Result).

Result = tree(1,[tree(6,[tree(7,[])]),tree(3,[]),tree(2,[tree(5,[])])])
```

The node 4 was under node 2 in the given tree. It is removed and node 2 now has the only child node 5.

Does this answer help you and your friends ?

Answer (score 3):

Prolog variables are immutable - their value cannot be changed.
So, if you want to change a tree say 3-way tree, you have a predicate that state the desired change.

A simple non-recursif case to replace specific nodes with new values:

```
replace_left_node(tree(_,B,C), NewNode, tree(NewNode, B, C).
replace_right_node(tree(A,B,_), NewNode, tree(A, B, NewNode).
replace_middle_node(tree(A,_,C), NewNode, tree(A, NewNode, C).
```

For a recursif case, you have to specify the change in greater detail. Say, in a tree with left & right sub trees and node value in the middle argument, replace node values having the value a by the value b, such as:

```
replace(a, b).           % replace the value a by value b
replace(X, X) :- X \= a. % otherwise use the same value unchanged
```

The recursive situation is to do the same to the Left and Right sub-trees.

```
replace_recursively(terminal, terminal) % this is the tree leaf
replace_recursively(tree(L, V, R), tree(L1, V1, R1)) :-
    replace(V, V1),             % handle the node value
    replace_recursively(L, L1), % handle left sub-tree
    replace_recursively(R, R1). % handle right sub-tree
```

Does this answer your question ? What else do you need ?

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But we figured out the solution for binary trees. How would one go about solving this for multiway trees?

Comment: You have to extend what you have for binary trees to multiway trees. Start by defining what is a multiway tree, for the benefit of all readers here. Maybe something like https://www.tutorialspoint.com/multi-way-trees. Then carefully define a sample tree in Prolog terms. If the arity is variable at each node, you probably have a list of terms. Et cetra.